# Search in Solr Error when metada have whitespaces and colon QUERY LUCENE 3.5

Tags: solr

i have mi metadata something like this:

<data>

<d>Top:Usuarios:Usuarios Tecnologia:Programador</d>

</data>

<data>

<d>Top:Usuarios:Usuarios Tecnologia:Analista</d>

</data>
<data>

<d>Top:Usuarios:Usuarios:Abogado</d>

</data>

And i want to search something like this (in regexp): Top:Usuarios:Usuarios Tecnologia.+
i have solr 3.5
If is a regex query or anyelse.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> And i want to search something like this (in regexp):
>   Top:Usuarios:Usuarios Tecnologia.

You need to espace [1,2] those special characters (colon) with a backslash. What client are you using to search?

**CURL**
`curl http://localhost:8983/solr/select?select?q=d:Top\\:Usuarios\\:Usuarios Tecnologia\\:Analista`

**Web Browser**
`http://localhost:8983/solr/select?select?q=d:Top\:Usuarios\:Usuarios Tecnologia\:Analista`

[1] http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax#NOTE:_URL_Escaping_Special_Characters
[2] http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Best-Solr-escaping-td3365943.html